# How to return auto generated id in insert query in postgres sql

Tags: c#, postgresql-9.1

I have a table.this is the script for my table:-

```
CREATE TABLE news
(
  news_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('news_seq'::regclass),
  title character varying(1024),
  description character varying(2024),
  CONSTRAINT pk_news_newsid PRIMARY KEY (news_id)  
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE news OWNER TO viewer;
```

Now I want to get the auto generated  `news_id` on insert the new record in the table.

**This is C# function for insert the news:-**

```
 public Int64 AddNews(News newNews)
    {
        string query = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            string dateFormat = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DateFormat"];
            NpgsqlParameter[] parm = new NpgsqlParameter[2];
            parm[0] = new NpgsqlParameter("title", newNews.NewsTitle);
            parm[1] = new NpgsqlParameter("des", newNews.NewsDescription);

            query = @" INSERT INTO   news(title, description)
                            VALUES   (:title, :des) 
                         Returning   news_id";

            int id=NpgSqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connectionString, CommandType.Text, query, parm);

            return id;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

`On executing this function I always get the -1 value`

Thanks in advance

While executing the following query on pgAdmin gives correct result:

```
INSERT INTO news(title, description)
    VALUES ('title','description')
    Returning news_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteScalar.html) or the equivalent for the API you are using?

Comment: Because all I see is `NpgSqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: @facebook-100001745831878 well that is probably your problem. ExecuteNonQuery returns **The number of rows affected if known; -1 otherwise**. Read the link that I posted for ExecuteScalar.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities I see:

1) the -1 value indicates you are hitting a rollback situation.  When you execute the function, check the table: did the record successfully insert or did some other situation cause a rollback?  If so, find what is causing the rollback (see #2).

2) the -1 value also can be returned if you are running a non-insert statement.  I realize you ARE running an insert, but what about any TRIGGERS on this table?  Are you doing any Select statements in the trigger?

Hope this helps.

Comment: The fact that the query works in stand-alone fashion indicates the C# is the culprit.  I would check parms and again, do the test in #1 above.  Are you getting a successful record insertion?